Mount storage in LXC container from Proxmox
I've mounted new LXC container from Proxmox with Ubuntu 22.x. In this container, i've added Frigate with Docker and docker-compose.
I'm trying to use Proxmox storage for save all videos/pics. For this, i've an storage named luna-storage in Proxmox resource :

For share this storage in my container, i've added new resource :

And, from my docker-compose, share this folder with docker container :

It seems that the config from Proxmox does not work. From my LXC container, i see all folders in /mnt/luna-storage/frigate/medias from the docker container :

But, from Proxmox PVE, the folder is empty :

I think that my configuration or my sharing of storage between Proxmox and my LXC container is not correct. But I can't find it.
Anyone have any idea where I made a mistake ?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I had this issue and found that of all the overlapping (and sometimes conflicting) advice on this topic I used the insructiosn here:
https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Unprivileged_LXC_containers
to map my unprivileged proxmox ct to NAS storage.
Cheers
